# JPA - How to remove failed "command" from entitymanager

Tags: java, jpa, rollback

I have a table filled with books. Every book has an amount. The table has a constraint, which does not allow the amount to became <0. If i merge a book which has an amount of less than 0, the commit will throw a RollbackException. And here comes the problem. As far as i understood the merge-method, it generates sql in the background, adds it to a list and with every commit the entitymanager runs through that list and executes every sql-command it can find.
But the command, which wants to update the amount to less than 0 is still in this list, because it couldnt be executed. So every following commit will fail because the constraint let the one command fail.

how to remove a command from the entitymanager in the catch-clause of the commit? I tried removing the entity and reloading it from the database with a query, but this didnt work

Current code:

```
book.setAmount(book.getAmount()-1);
EntityTransaction transaction = this.entityManager.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
try{
 this.entityManager.merge(book);
 transaction.commit();
catch(RollbackException re){
 // TODO: remove the failed statemeant somehow
}
```

thanks, basti

Comment: This might not work since (depending on your environment/managed transactions/manual transactions) the transaction is marked for `isRollbackOnly()` and you are not to complete your transaction anymore.

Comment: so is it a bug? the transaction is already closed in the catch-clause. and the changes are not committed. so i would guess when the error came up, it made an rollback, closed then transaction and threw it then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your transaction you have an operation that fails and others that do not (it it not clear which other opearations are trying to be commited, as we do not see what other code is executed before the transaction). With JPA you do not have access to the list of operations that JPA will do, but rather you controll what is committed, by doing different stuff in different transactions. So, what you could do is simply trying to do that `EntityManager.merge()` in a different transaction (and before that transaction, either create a new `EntityManager` or call `EntityManager.clear()`).

Also do note, that it is strongly recommended (at least with Hibernate) to throw/garbage-collect the `EntityManager` that throws Exceptions, so do not reuse it after that exception.

PS: As I see, you use an EntityManager with a transaction type of `RESOURCE_LOCAL`.

Comment: my merge is running in a update method. it is like public void updateBook(Book b){b.setAmount(...);transaction.begin();entitymanager.merge(b);transaction.commit()} so there is for every single merge a single transaction. but if one update fails, all following will fail with the reason, that the constraint siad "no, you dont", because the failed command will be executed with every commit. i need to remove it somehow

Comment: You are reusing the same `EntityManager`instance for different transactions, which is BAD, as after one fails with an exception, it could remain in an inconsistent state. Do you use hibernate or EclipseLink?

Comment: Then read [Hibernate Exception Handling](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Entity_Manager_Reference_Guide/transactions-demarcation-exceptions.html). That means, that after an exception is thrown, you MUST close the entityManager and throw it away. If you need some other DB operations, then simply create a new `EntityManager`, which is very cheap from performance point of view.